# Are the strong and the weak operator topology well defined in abstract C* and Von Neumann algebras?

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras

If $A$ is an abstract $C^*$ algebra, then a $A$ is isometrically isomorphic to a subalgebra of bounded operators $B(H)$ for some Hilbert space $H$. We can restrict the weak operator toplogy and the strong operator topology of $B(H)$ to $A$.

Are these definitions independent of $H$? And what about the case of $A$ being an abstract Von Neummann Algebra (a $C^*$ algebra who has a predual)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the weak and strong operator topologies depend strongly on the chosen representation.

For example, if you represent $C([0,1])$ on $L^2([0,1])$ by multiplication operators, then the functions $$f_n(x) = x^n$$ converge strongly to zero.  However, if you take the direct sume of that representation with the one dimensional representation corresponding to the character
$$f\mapsto f(1),$$
then the $f_n$ do not converge strongly to any $f$ in $C([0,1])$.

Comment: I was wondering if we can generalize the concept of strongly continuos 1-parameter group, a group homomorphism $ \phi:\mathbb R \longrightarrow GL(H)$ continuos with the strong operator topology, to the abstract $C^*$ algebra setting. So, is this impossible? I think the answer may be 'no' because your answer